# how can I run this pipeline with color streaming on Gstreamer

Tags: python, gstreamer, rtsp, direct3d

I'm trying to this pipeline running on my webcam using python.

"rtspsrc location=rtsp://... ! parsebin ! d3d11h265dec ! d3d11convert !
video/x-raw(memory:D3D11Memory), format=(string)NV12 ! d3d11download ! appsink"

Answer (score 0):

rtspsrc may not be self enough, so you may have to specify caps after such as (for RTP/H265)

```
rtspsrc location=rtsp://... ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H265 ! rtph265depay ! decodebin3 ! ...
```

Or you may use uridecodebin:

```
uridecodebin uri=rtsp://... ! d3d11convert ! ...
```

Also be sure that your appsink supports reading frames from D3D11Memory, if not convert back to system memory.